# chain ajax requests in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I have a form that uses autocomplete, I can retrieve the data on the input field but I can't figure out how to get the description data. what I would like to do is get the value from the user then call another controller to get the additional information using ajax (that way I can get more information if needed). Thanks

View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function() {
    $( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({ url: "<?php echo site_url('test/suggestions'); ?>",
            data: { term: $("#autocomplete").val()},
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function(data){
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    minLength: 2

    });
});
});
</script>

<label for="title">Job Title</label>
<input name="title" type="text" id="autocomplete" />

<label for="description">Description</label>
<p id="description" /></p>
```

Controller

```
 function suggestions()
{
    $this->load->model('tp_model');
    $term = $this->input->post('term',TRUE);

    if (strlen($term) < 1) break;

    $rows = $this->tp_model->GetAutocomplete(array('keyword' => $term));

    $title_array = array();
    $description_array = array();


    foreach ($rows as $row){
         array_push($title_array, $row->title); 
         array_push($description_array, $row->description);

}
    echo json_encode($title_array);     

}
```

Model

```
  function GetAutocomplete($options = array())
{

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('test');
    $this->db->like('title', $options['keyword'], 'after');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the description from your controller using "[select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select)" event for autocomplete.

```
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: ...,
    .....,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var id = ui.item.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: description_fetch_url, //another controller
            data: "descritpion_id="+id,
            ....
            success: function(data) {
                $("#description").html(data)
            } 
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: autocomplete is a jQuery UI method. You have to load jQuery UI in order to use it.

Comment: @user1190992 I like what you added but I'm not sure how to implement it within my current project. Is this a stand alone script or is it added within the current script. If so where is it added. I'm still new to ajax so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @KevinBeal JQuery UI is loaded and autocomplete works fine, what I need is a way to take the value of autocomplete and execute another ajax function.

Comment: @sfjamrock why don't you put another ajax request inside of the success handler for the first ajax request?

Comment: @KevinBeal Thanks for your input, I did as you suggest and created another function that receives the autocomplete data and pass it to another function that executed another ajax call and got the additional data.